# lose connection in one way on local network without firewall windows server 2008 r2

Tags: windows, networking, windows-server-2008-r2, ping

we have 2 computers in our local network a few day ago we encounter an wired problem sometime network connectivity from computer one to computer two lose and we can't ping computer two from computer one but computer two can't ping computer one and both of them can be pinged in other computers in our local network.

both computers are running windows server 2008 r2 and firewall set off on them.we also have kaspresky installed on then which firewall off it is set off

Answer (score 0):

I'd like advice you to turn on the `kaspersky firewall`, then add these allow rules to that:
`Incoming ICMP Stream`
`ICMP Echo Reply incoming packets`
After that you should add your network and set your network status to `Local Network` or `Trusted Network` on `network tab` in `kaspersky firewall`.